Order of evaluation of function in Haskell – call to ++
I'm new to Haskell and don't get how the following function is evaluated:
    test1 1 ls = ls
    test1 p ls = test1 (p - 1) ls ++ [p]

By the simple scheme below I assumed the answer should be [3, 2],
but evaluation in ghci gives [2, 3]. Why is that?
    {-
    test1 3 [] =
        test1 2 []++[3] =
            test1 1 []++[3]++[2]
    -}


It’s not clear if this is what’s tripping you up, but note that the precedence is (teste1 (p - 1) ls) ++ [p] – function application binds tighter than anything else.

Thanks, Ry-. That's it. With this precedence I understand how it gets evaluated.

Function application usually takes precedence over operators, so:
test1 1 ls = ls
test1 p ls = test1 (p - 1) ls ++ [p]

is interpreted as:
test1 1 ls = ls
test1 p ls = (test1 (p - 1) ls) ++ [p]

This will thus get evaluated as:
test1 3 []
  -> (test1 2 []) ++ [3]
  -> (test1 1 [] ++ [2]) ++ [3]
  -> ([] ++ [2]) ++ [3]
  -> [2, 3]

The algorithm is however not very efficient: appending to the right takes (n) with n the number of items of the left sublist, making the test1 function run in (n2). We can work with an accumulator here:
test1 n xs = xs ++ go n []
  where go 1 xs = xs
        go p xs = go (p-1) (p:xs)

This makes the algorithm (n). This is especially useful if for example ls would already be a very large list, and will also save memory, since we don't make a lot of copies of ls, but just reuse the ls list.
